# how to send an activation code in asp.net mvc2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, activation-codes

there is a send activation code button. A click on the button. it should send the activation code to the customer. i don't find any useful article for this. anybody can  explain?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to generate and store some kind of secret information unique to a particular user, then send in an email or something with a link back to your application. You could read the secret back from the query string, or link to a page with a login and a textbox to enter it. However you want to work the page.

Compare the secret and user credentials given against the stored value.

This is fairly naive approach that doesnt even attempt to tackle some serious security concerns with this type of setup, but for a simple one off email verification you can get away with it.

Just be extremely careful about what type of data you intend to send to your users in any emails.